Astronomical nova or supernova (Ia) - what peak intensity and wavelength to expect in the UV, extinction coefficient of ozone layer?
see https://www.nasa.gov/centers-and-facilities/marshall/nasa-global-astronomers-await-rare-nova-explosion/. T Coronae Borealis is expected to go nova. Distance 2630 light-years. Its magnitude is supposed to rise from 11 to 2 (3.5 orders of magnitude). At magnitude 2, it will just be a bright star. Wiki however claims:

"Under certain conditions, mass accretion can eventually trigger runaway fusion that destroys the white dwarf rather than merely expelling its atmosphere. In this case, the event is usually classified as a Type Ia supernova."

Under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Ia_supernova wiki cites:

"The typical visual absolute magnitude of Type Ia supernovae is Mv = −19.3 (about 5 billion times brighter than the Sun), with little variation."

Little chance of that happening, but if it did, then what shielding would the ozone layer provide? I guess the visible magnitude (corrected for distance) would be -9.8, close to the -7.5 of SN 1006 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SN_1006). Without ozone layer shielding, the UV of such point source could be harmful for the naked eye. Would the black body spectrum be relevant? If not, then which spectrum? That of a hydrogen bomb? How to estimate the net Absorbance of the ozone layer over the expected frequencies?

There is no need for any complicated calculation - the additional UV flux is a tiny fraction of what is already received from the Sun.
The apparent magnitude of the Sun is about -27, so if the peak apparent magnitude of a Type Ia supernova at 2630 light years is about -10 (I haven't checked this), then this represents a $<10^{-6}$ fractional increase in flux hitting the Earth's atmosphere - totally negligible.
This assumes a spectrum similar to that of the Sun. Type Ia supernovae spectra aren't quite like the Sun and look very little like blackbodies. There is flux over a broad range of wavelengths, peaking at around 400 nm, but with lots of deep absorption features attributed to various chemical elements in the ejects (e.g. review by Parrent et al. 2014).
Foley et al. (2016) present HST observations of the UV and optical spectra of several type Ia supernovae near maximum. They are quite diverse in the UV region, but their UV spectral intensity is at least 1.5 orders of magnitude lower than at visible wavelengths. Tables are provided that could give the data needed for detailed calculation of the UV flux and hence how much energy might be absorbed in Earth's atmosphere. However, the spectrum is not UV-rich enough to counteract the basic conclusion I started with and the additional UV flux from a supernova at 2630 light years is negligible.
